# Simple Mod rewrite not working. Attempting to mask file name

Tags: php, .htaccess

This seems really basic and I am not sure why it is not working. I simply want to be able to use `www.mydomain.com/sso-login` to load the contents of `www.mydomain.com/login.php`. This is the code that I am using in my .htaccess file and it is taking me to a 404 page when I type the url `www.mydomain.com/sso-login`.  Any ideas why this isn't working?  Other url rewrites are working in the same .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/sso-login$ /login.php [L]
```

Comment: If this is in .htaccess rather than the server-level config, remove the leading `/`.  `RewriteRule ^sso-login$ login.php [L]` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^sso-login/?$ /login.php [L]
</IfModule>
```